# Knockout JS: Display binded subList foreach meta items using exapnd option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

This is my data structure.

```
=MetaData=
School
College
Home

=SubDetails=
School
    ClassRooms
    Library 
    OfficeRoom
College
    AdminOffice
    Departments
    Lab
    PlacementHall
Home
    LivingRoom
    StudyRoom
    Hall
    DiningHall
    Portico
```

The meta data values will be selected using drop-down menu. For example if school is the value chosen from drop-down menu then the display area should show as:

```
+ school x
```

Once I clicked that + expand icon in my case it should list the details as in data.

```
- School x
    ClassRooms
    Library 
    OfficeRoom
```

For example if I continuously choosing more than one item, say school, college, home  etc

```
- School x
    ClassRooms
    Library 
    OfficeRoom
+ College x
- Home x
    LivingRoom
    StudyRoom
    Hall
    DiningHall
    Portico
```

Code I tried:

HTML:

```
<div class="DataDisplay">
    <!-- ko foreach: selectedMetaDataList -->
    <span class="metaHeader">
            <span>
                <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.expandMetaData"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="padding-right: 3px;"></i></a>
                <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
                <span class="combineImgText">
                    <img data-bind="click: $parent.remove" class="delfilter" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/icon_x_purple_on.png")" width="15" height="15" />
                </span>
            </span>
        </span><br />
    <!-- /ko -->
    <span class="subDetails" style="display: none">
        <!-- ko foreach: selectedSubDetailsList -->
        <span data-bind="text: $data" style="margin-left:25px"></span><span class="combineImgText">
            <img data-bind="click: $parent.remove" class="delfilter" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/icon_x_purple_on.png")" width="15" height="15" />
        </span><br />
        <!-- /ko -->
    </span>                             
</div>
```

JS:

```
if(//matching condition)
{
    selectedMetaDataList.push(selectedMetaData().toString()); //ko.observableArray([])
    selectedSubDetailsList.push(value[i]); //ko.observableArray([])
}

expandMetaData: function () {          
    expandData($(".subDetails").is(':visible') ? true : false);
    $(".subDetails").toggle();
},
```

The problem is if I select more than one, then only lastly added element if expandable and it included all the sub-details of the previously selected items. My question is How to bind particular selected meta data to display its sub details content. I am struggling with this for past two days :(

Any suggestion would be helpfui!

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: You are not showing enough code. Make a code sample actually works that reproduces the problem. You can then remove all the screenshots and details about your database structure, because they are not really needed to answer the question.

Comment: Okay, Let me add a fiddle for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best advice I can give you, without seeing your viewmodels, is:

- Your view models don't have to copy your data-structure. They are a layer between your data and your view, so you can make changes that benefit the way you want to render things.
- Don't use jQuery to hide/show stuff, use knockout's default data-binds: `visible` or `css`

To illustrate these points:

- A viewmodel that includes a reference to details *inside* the main category
- A `visible` binding to hide and show
- An `expanded` state in the viewmodels that automatically updates several parts of the UI

```js
var metaData = [
  "School",
  "College",
  "Home"
];

var subDetails = {
  School: [
    "ClassRooms",
    "Library",
    "OfficeRoom"
  ],
  College: [
    "AdminOffice",
    "Departments",
    "Lab",
    "PlacementHall"
  ],
  Home: [
    "LivingRoom",
    "StudyRoom",
    "Hall",
    "DiningHall",
    "Portico"
  ]
};

// An important purpose of this view model is to include details _inside_ a meta item
var MetaViewModel = function(label) {
  // Expanded is used to bind to the visiblity of the details
  this.expanded = ko.observable(false);
  
  // Add a '+' or '-' sign based on expanded state
  this.label = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return (this.expanded() ? "- " : "+ ") + label;
  }, this);
  
  // Here, we add the details to the item
  this.details = ko.observableArray(subDetails[label]);
  
  // Toggle flips the state of expanded
  this.toggle = function() {
    this.expanded(!this.expanded());
  }.bind(this);
  
  // Removes a detail from the item's details list
  this.remove = function(str) {
    this.details.remove(str);
  }.bind(this);
};

MetaViewModel.create = function(label) { return new MetaViewModel(label); };

var viewModel = {
   meta: metaData.map(MetaViewModel.create) // Creates a new viewmodel for each meta data category
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: meta">
  <li>
    <div data-bind="text: label, click: toggle"></div>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: details, visible: expanded">
      <li data-bind="text: $data + ' X', click: $parent.remove"></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats Amazing. Thanks mcuh :)